# Cannot read /.conkyrc : Is a directory

Tags: ubuntu, conky

I just installed conky which I can run normally.
I installed a theme and made a .conkyrc folder in my home directory. When i am trying to run conky I got this message:

`conky: cannot read /home/.../.conkyrc: Is a directory`

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to the conky 1.10.8 man file, the default configuration file location (in userspace) is `$HOME/.config/conky/conky.conf`. However, the default location was formerly `$HOME/.conkyrc` (I'm not sure when it was changed...), and a check of this location was probably retained in later conky versions for backward compatibility. I use conky 1.10.8 (upgraded over the years), still have my config file at `$HOME/.conkyrc`, and conky still takes it as a default location. So, conky is looking for a file named `.conkyrc` rather than a folder with that name in $HOME.

Change your folder (i.e. directory) name to something other than `.conkyrc`, and conky should no longer generate the "cannot read" message.

Also, as noted in `man conky`, if you want to load a config file from a location other than the default, you can use the `-c` command line option.